# Elastic Search Sort by text error: illegal_argument_exception

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, search, text, field

I have the below index configuration for Products in Elastic Search.

```
{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "number_of_shards": 3,
            "number_of_replicas": 0
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "fields": {
                    "original": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                },
                "type": "text",
                "fielddata": true,
                "analyzer": "portuguese"
            },
            "product_data": {
                "type": "object"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HERE I UPSERT THE DATA

`http://127.0.0.1:9200/product2/_update/IMOB01`

**BODY**

```
{
    "doc": {
        "name":"Test",
        "product_data": {
            "symbol": "IMOB01",
            "release_date": "2013-01-01T00:00:00"
        }
    },
    "doc_as_upsert": true
}
```

**RESPONSE**
201 created

**The problem is**, if I try **_search** and **sort** by **name** everything is  OK.
BUT if for instance,  I try use **_Search** with **sort** by **product_data.symbol **  I receive the error below...

`localhost:9200/product/_search`

**BODY**

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 50,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "match": {
                    "product_data.symbol": "imob01"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sort": [
         { "product_data.symbol": {"order": "asc", "unmapped_type" : "text"}}
    ]
}
```

**REPONSE**

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                "reason": "Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [product_data.symbol] in order to load field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use significant memory."
            }
        ],
        "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
        "reason": "all shards failed",
        "phase": "query",
        "grouped": true,
        "failed_shards": [
            {
                "shard": 0,
                "index": "product",
                "node": "PfwDOAwzTZm63IHq_rt1TA",
                "reason": {
                    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                    "reason": "Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [product_data.symbol] in order to load field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use significant memory."
                }
            }
        ],
        "caused_by": {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [product_data.symbol] in order to load field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use significant memory.",
            "caused_by": {
                "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                "reason": "Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [product_data.symbol] in order to load field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use significant memory."
            }
        }
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

**What I`m doing wrong ?**

OBS: The reason that I created the product_data as object is because I have some products with different types of return, they can have symbol or other fields, **symbol is just a example.**

I tried change the type of product_data for fielddata:true with no success.

Answer (score 0):

> Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document
> field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are
> disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead.
> Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [product_data.symbol] in order to
> load field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can
> use significant memory.

Try user keyword type:

```
   "sort": [
         { "product_data.symbol.keyword": {"order": "asc", "unmapped_type" : "text"}}
    ]
```